# Fiori source code not working properly when update SAPUI5 Version

Tags: sapui5

I've a SAPUI5 Fiori application which has a smart table. And in that smart table I've to control the visibility of some buttons in columns according to some conditions. The below code is working fine with **SAPUI5 version 1.63.0** and below.

```
    <m:HBox alignItems="Center" justifyContent="SpaceAround">
        <m:Button type="Transparent" press="onPDFDetailViewPress" icon="sap-icon://detail-view" tooltip="{i18n>pdfDetailReportTooltip}"
        visible="{parts: [{path: 'ASSIGNED_STATUS'}],formatter: '.formatDisplayReport'}"/>
        <m:Button type="Transparent" press="onSummaryViewPress" icon="sap-icon://measure" tooltip="{i18n>pdfSummaryReportTooltip}"
 visible="{parts: [{path: 'ASSIGNED_STATUS'}],formatter: '.formatDisplayReport'}"/>
        </m:HBox>
```

And my formatter in the controller

```
formatDisplayReport: function (sAssignedStatus) {
        if (sAssignedStatus&& sAssignedStatus!== null && sAssignedStatus.toString() === "3") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This code works fine and displays the two buttons according to the conditions correctly with SAPUI5 version 1.63.0 and below.
**But it won't work with SAPUI5 versions above from 1.63.0**. 
But some other similar conditions works fine when updating the SAPUI5 version.
What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in the debugger? Is the code called? What's the value of sAssignedStatus?

Comment: when I set the breakpoint the function getting called and the value is nul.. this happens only for versions greater than 1.63

Comment: Why is your syntax so complicated? `{ path: 'ASSIGNED_STATUS', formatter: '.formatDisplayReport' }` should be sufficient.

Comment: I checked that also.. still the problem exists

Comment: Then you should check why ASSIGNED_STATUS is null. Since we don't know your model structure it's hard to help.

Comment: will check.. the problem is this happens only with sapui5 version change

Comment: At the moment it seems unlikely that anything was introduced/changed in 1.63 which would affect such basic functionality.
Would it be possible for you to create an example in a tool like https://plnkr.co/ ?
This might help to analyze the issue.